# Keep getting [object] [Object] from variable

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the value of the variable `$target` but when I print it I keep getting [object] [Object] for the value. I am new to jQuery so this is probably a very simple problem something I am missing.

```
$("body").click(function(event) {
            var $target = $(event.target.id);
        $("#log").html("clicked: " + $target);
        });
```

Comment: Why are you calling `$()`?

Comment: you might want to read up on javascript if you don't understand what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you're turning `event.target.id` into a jquery object. you don't need the `$()` around it:

```
var target = event.target.id;
$("#log").html("clicked: " + target);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the jQuery wrapp `$()`, otherwise you get a jQuery "*object*"

```
$("body").click(function (event) {
    var target = event.target.id;
    $("#log").html("clicked: " + target);
});
```

**Option 2:**  use jQuery wrapper but get id with [.attr('id')](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$("body").click(function (event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);
    $("#log").html("clicked: " + $target.prop('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `$target` is an object. When using string concatenation (the `+` operator with one of the operands being a string), an object gets translated to `"[object] [Object]"` hence your output. If you're just looking for the id of the element you clicked you can use:

```
$("body").click(function(event) {
    $("#log").html("clicked: " + event.target.id);
});
```

To understand why `$target` is an object note that you passed a string (i.e. the value of `event.target.id`) into `$()`. `$()` then takes that argument and returns a jQuery object.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/